# How to update or modify any value in vuetifyjs text-field?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm a newbie with vuejs.
I'm trying to create some custom number keyboard like:

[image]

Here is my HTML code

```
<input type="text" @click="keyboard($event)" v-model="box.height"/>
<input type="text" @click="keyboard($event)" v-model="box.width"/>
<input type="text" @click="keyboard($event)" v-model="box.length"/>
<input type="text" @click="keyboard($event)" v-model="box.weight"/>
```

Methods

```
export default {
   data: () => ({
      active: null,
      box: {
          height: '2.0'
          width: '3.0',
          length: '2.5',
          weight: '0.5'
      }
   }),
   methods: {
      keyboardValue(keyboardValue) {
          var latestValue = ''
          if(this.active !== null){
            latestValue = this.active.target.value += keyboardValue
            this.active.target.value = latestValue;
            this.active.target.focus()
          }
      },
      keyboard($event){
        this.active = $event
      },
  }
}
```

I achieved as expected with input HTML. GIF image is what I achieved but with vuetify I can't update or modify any value.

Here are the vuetify component

```
<v-text-field label="Height" @click="keyboard($event)" v-model="box.height"></v-text-field>
<v-text-field label="Width" @click="keyboard($event)" v-model="box.width"></v-text-field>
<v-text-field label="Length" @click="keyboard($event)" v-model="box.length"></v-text-field>
<v-text-field label="Weight" @click="keyboard($event)" v-model="box.weight"></v-text-field>
```

Define @click="" and update active text field value. Make it work as a virtual keyboard. How can I get or update any value?

Here is the codepen link
[Demo](https://codepen.io/yurenlimbu/pen/qBbPjrd)

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code for the keypad buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it needs to be tied to the v-model of the text-fields. Assign each `text-field` a data var.

```
<v-text-field label="Height" @click="keyboard('h')" v-model="h"></v-text-field>
<v-text-field label="Width" @click="keyboard('w')" v-model="w"></v-text-field>
<v-text-field label="Length" @click="keyboard('l')" v-model="l"></v-text-field>
```

Then set the `active` data var and update...

```
methods: {
      keyboardValue(keyboardValue) {
          if (this.active !== null) {
            this[this.active] = (this[this.active]||'') + keyboardValue
          }
      },
      keyboard(model){
        this.active = model
      },
}
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/I4Ln8HfNJF)

Comment: Thanks! @Zim, Sorry for the late reply. Can I make a dynamic? Suppose there are 20-25 text field now I have to define v-model and assign in data it takes too long. Is there anyway to short way?

Comment: @user2389511 please update the question and accept the answer. I will then answer the modified question

Comment: I modified the question and accept your answer. Can you check it? Please.